# Camel route - filter on file name and set header value

Tags: apache-camel, routes

My requirement is seemingly straightforward.  I need to poll a single directory and based on the file name of the input file I need to;

a) Set a header value 
b) Direct the message to a particular JMS queue

I have tried a couple of different ways to acheive this but based on the docs the followng should work.. obviously for me it doesn't...

```
        <from uri="file:[some input directory]"/>

        <when>
            <simple>${file:name} contains 'new'</simple>
            <setHeader headerName="messageType">
                <constant>NEW</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="jmsbroker:queue:[queue for new items]"/>
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${file:name} contains 'amend'</simple>
            <setHeader headerName="messageType">
                <constant>AMEND</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="jmsbroker:queue:[queue for amended items]"/>
        </when>
        <when>
            <simple>${file:name} contains 'other'</simple>
            <setHeader headerName="messageType">
                <constant>OTHER</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="jmsbroker:queue:[queue for other]"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <bean ref="deadLetterErrorHandler"/>
        </otherwise>

    </route>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Andy

Answer (score 2):

you are missing `<choice>` around `<when>` conditionals (see the [content based router docs](http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html))

also, your `<otherwise>` section should just route to an error queue or throw an exception...

try something like this...

```
    <route>
        <from uri="file:/tmp/inbox"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${file:name} contains 'new'</simple>
                <setHeader headerName="messageType">
                    <constant>NEW</constant>
                </setHeader>
                <to uri="jmsbroker:queue:newItems"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <to uri="jmsbroker:queue:errorQueue"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```